# Easy way to get a single resultset from three identical tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The DB I'm working with has three tables with identical column layouts, OPEX, NOPEX and CAPEX. I would like to query all three for items with a matching `AssetId` and get a single result set so that I can process them all at the same time in my .Net code.

The twist is that I do need to know which table they came from.

I know I can do this with a series of CASE in the SELECT clause, perhaps using the ID column in each where it's non-zero to decide which of the tables it came from. But I would have to have one for each column and the tables are pretty wide.

Is there some other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Select 'O' as flag, * from OPEX UNION ALL SELECT 'N' as flag, * FROM NOPEXX UNION ALL...etc

Comment: well that was fast!

Comment: @Cato doesn't satisfy requirement for matching AssetID

Comment: @TJB, yeah I know, but it's just to give a general idea, I'd expect someone to be able to apply their WHERE clauses as needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get them into one set, you would use a combination of UNION and EXISTS() checks. The UNION ALL will give you a single result set that contains data from all three tables, and the EXISTS check on each will confirm the table you are querying from has corresponding records in the other tables.

```
SELECT *, 'OPEX' AS table_name 
FROM OPEX o
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 1 
FROM NOPEX n
WHERE n.asset_id = o.asset_id)
AND EXISTS (
SELECT 1 
FROM CAPEX c
WHERE c.asset_id = o.asset_id)

UNION ALL 

SELECT *, 'NOPEX' AS table_name 
FROM NOPEX n
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 1 
FROM Opex o
WHERE o.asset_id = n.asset_id)
AND EXISTS (
SELECT 1 
FROM CAPEX c
WHERE c.asset_id = n.asset_id)

UNION ALL 

SELECT *, 'CAPEX' AS table_name  
FROM CAPEX c
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 1 
FROM Opex o
WHERE o.asset_id = c.asset_id)
AND EXISTS (
SELECT 1 
FROM NOPEX n
WHERE n.asset_id = c.asset_id)
```

I guess you could also do INNER JOINs?

```
SELECT c.*, 'CAPEX' AS table_name  
FROM CAPEX c
INNER JOIN OPEX o
ON o.asset_id = c.asset_id
INNER JOIN NOPEX n
ON n.asset_id = c.asset_id

UNION ALL 

SELECT o.*, 'OPEX' AS table_name 
FROM OPEX o
INNER JOIN CAPEX c
ON c.asset_id = o.asset_id
INNER JOIN NOPEX n
ON n.asset_id = o.asset_id

UNION ALL 

SELECT n.*, 'NOPEX' AS table_name 
FROM NOPEX n
INNER JOIN OPEX o
ON o.asset_id = n.asset_id
INNER JOIN CAPEX c
ON c.asset_id = n.asset_id
```

Comment: I used the union and flag column, which worked perfectly. The tables in question are small enough that the performance is not going to be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Similar answer to dfundako, but resolving sooner where `AssetId` is in all three tables and less hitting of the indexes on the related tables:

```
;with cte as (
    select
    AssetID
    from (
        select distinct
        AssetID
        from Opex
        union all
        select distinct
        AssetID
        from Nopex
        union all
        select distinct
        AssetID
        from Capex
        ) as AssetIDs
    group by AssetId
    having count(AssetId) = 3
    )

select 'Opex', * from Opex as o
inner join cte 
    on o.AssetID = cte.AssetID
union all
select 'Nopex', * from Nopex as n
inner join cte 
    on n.AssetID = cte.AssetID
union all
select 'Capex', * from Capex as c
inner join cte 
    on c.AssetID = cte.AssetID
```